# (Scale) Transform Animation on UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewanimation, cgaffinetransform

My goal is to create a "bubble-up" animation to a `UITextView` that is being nested in a `UIView` card presented modally.

While the card appears, the `UITextView` doesn't seem to..is there some workaround for this? Below is the code I have tried thus far...

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.1, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.cardView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)              
            self.messageTextView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)  
        }, completion: nil)            
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    cardView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0, y: 0)
    messageTextView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0, y: 0)
}
```

Comment: is there a reason for the DispatchQueue in this instance? Or is it just personal preference? Because I am 100% certain the animation block will no block the main thread.

Comment: I don’t believe there is an issue with you code just move it to the viewDidApear instead of viewWillApear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the exact setting, so show the storyboard. I did not add the constrain but setNeedsLayout before animation. Hope it works for you.

[image]

```
          override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.messageTextView.setNeedsLayout()
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.1, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.cardView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
                self.messageTextView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did a test and I had to add height and width constraints to my `UITextView`s or they collapse to zero size and aren't visible.

Also note that you should use a small non-zero scale value like 0.01 for your small size rather than 0, at least for shrinking a view. If you try to animate a view's scale down to zero it disappears rather than shrinking.

### Edit:

I also tried your spring damped animation, and found that with the values of `usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8` that you're using, the spring effect is barely noticeable. If I dial the damping down to 0.5, the bouncing effect is better, but when animating the view shrinking, the view scale overshoots 0 scale and grows back upside-down slightly.

Comment: hmm i tried adding width/height constraints, incorporating a small non-zero scale value, and even added a background color to the textview to see it on the card's white backdrop, and while i see the textview animating, the actual static text doesn't appear..

Comment: So `cardView` is a `UILabel`?

Comment: it is a `uiview`